# How to create urilink.acsm

Tags: pdf, adobe, publishing, epub

Our partner was providing us unique .acsm links for our costumers and readers,but they will stop providing this service.

Now we should find other partner or do it ourself.

How to publish a book for Adobe Digital Editions and how to provide this links for downloading acsm files? Which tools to use? How to provide links and automatic emails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contact Adobe directly. You can find more information about Adobe Content Server at: http://www.adobe.com/products/content-server.html